# Error Create Datasource JBOSS 7.1.1 FINAL

Tags: mysql, datasource

## Error when deploying the server I get this error in jboss 7.1.1 final

log Error:

```
09:44:28,645 INFORMACIÓN [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
09:44:28,865 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
09:44:28,935 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
09:44:29,924 INFO  [org.xnio] XNIO Version 3.0.3.GA
09:44:29,924 INFO  [org.jboss.as.server] JBAS015888: Creating http management service using socket-binding (management-http)
09:44:29,944 INFO  [org.xnio.nio] XNIO NIO Implementation Version 3.0.3.GA
09:44:29,954 INFO  [org.jboss.remoting] JBoss Remoting version 3.2.3.GA
09:44:29,975 INFO  [org.jboss.as.configadmin] JBAS016200: Activating ConfigAdmin Subsystem
09:44:29,988 INFO  [org.jboss.as.logging] JBAS011502: Removing bootstrap log handlers
09:44:30,005 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 44) JBAS013101: Activating Security Subsystem
09:44:30,017 INFO  [org.jboss.as.security] (MSC service thread 1-2) JBAS013100: Current PicketBox version=4.0.7.Final
09:44:30,067 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 38) JBAS011800: Activating Naming Subsystem
09:44:30,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as.osgi] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 39) JBAS011940: Activating OSGi Subsystem
09:44:30,097 INFO  [org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 31) JBAS010280: Activating Infinispan subsystem.
09:44:30,109 INFO  [org.jboss.as.naming] (MSC service thread 1-4) JBAS011802: Starting Naming Service
09:44:30,125 INFO  [org.jboss.as.webservices] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 48) JBAS015537: Activating WebServices Extension
09:44:30,179 INFO  [org.jboss.as.mail.extension] (MSC service thread 1-3) JBAS015400: Bound mail session [java:jboss/mail/Default]
09:44:30,241 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBAS010408: Starting JCA Subsystem (JBoss IronJacamar 1.0.9.Final)
09:44:30,341 INFO  [org.jboss.ws.common.management.AbstractServerConfig] (MSC service thread 1-5) JBoss Web Services - Stack CXF Server 4.0.2.GA
09:44:30,350 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010403: Deploying JDBC-compliant driver class org.h2.Driver (version 1.3)
09:44:30,386 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.jdbc.Driver (version 5.1)
09:44:30,390 INFO  [org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS010404: Deploying non-JDBC-compliant driver class com.mysql.fabric.jdbc.FabricMySQLDriver (version 5.1)
09:44:30,393 ERROR [org.jboss.as.controller.management-operation] (ServerService Thread Pool -- 27) JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
    ("subsystem" => "datasources"),
    ("jdbc-driver" => "mysql")
]): org.jboss.msc.service.DuplicateServiceException: Service jboss.jdbc-driver.mysql is already registered
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceRegistrationImpl.setInstance(ServiceRegistrationImpl.java:154) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl.startInstallation(ServiceControllerImpl.java:227) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceContainerImpl.install(ServiceContainerImpl.java:560) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceTargetImpl.install(ServiceTargetImpl.java:201) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$ChildServiceTarget.install(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2228) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceBuilderImpl.install(ServiceBuilderImpl.java:307) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl$ContextServiceBuilder.install(OperationContextImpl.java:955) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.startDriverServices(JdbcDriverAdd.java:164) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.JdbcDriverAdd.performRuntime(JdbcDriverAdd.java:128) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:50) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourceEnable$1.execute(DataSourceEnable.java:91) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.connector.subsystems.datasources.DataSourceEnable$1.execute(DataSourceEnable.java:91) [jboss-as-connector-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:385) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:272) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:200) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:311) [jboss-as-controller-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [rt.jar:1.7.0_72]
    at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122) [jboss-threads-2.0.0.GA.jar:2.0.0.GA]

09:44:30,836 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-4) Arrancando Coyote HTTP/1.1 en puerto http-localhost-127.0.0.1-8080
```

---

jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\standalone\configuration\standalone.xml

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>

<server xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:1.2">
    <extensions>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.configadmin"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.connector"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.deployment-scanner"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ee"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.ejb3"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jaxrs"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jdr"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jmx"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.jpa"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.logging"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.mail"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.naming"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.osgi"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.pojo"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.remoting"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.sar"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.security"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.threads"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.transactions"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.web"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.webservices"/>
        <extension module="org.jboss.as.weld"/>
    </extensions>
    <management>
        <security-realms>
            <security-realm name="ManagementRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="mgmt-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
            <security-realm name="ApplicationRealm">
                <authentication>
                    <properties path="application-users.properties" relative-to="jboss.server.config.dir"/>
                </authentication>
            </security-realm>
        </security-realms>
        <management-interfaces>
            <native-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding native="management-native"/>
            </native-interface>
            <http-interface security-realm="ManagementRealm">
                <socket-binding http="management-http"/>
            </http-interface>
        </management-interfaces>
    </management>
    <profile>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:1.1">
            <console-handler name="CONSOLE">
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
            </console-handler>
            <periodic-rotating-file-handler name="FILE">
                <formatter>
                    <pattern-formatter pattern="%d{HH:mm:ss,SSS} %-5p [%c] (%t) %s%E%n"/>
                </formatter>
                <file relative-to="jboss.server.log.dir" path="server.log"/>
                <suffix value=".yyyy-MM-dd"/>
                <append value="true"/>
            </periodic-rotating-file-handler>
            <logger category="com.arjuna">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="sun.rmi">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb">
                <level name="WARN"/>
            </logger>
            <logger category="jacorb.config">
                <level name="ERROR"/>
            </logger>
            <root-logger>
                <level name="INFO"/>
                <handlers>
                    <handler name="CONSOLE"/>
                    <handler name="FILE"/>
                </handlers>
            </root-logger>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:configadmin:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:datasources:1.0">
            <datasources>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS" pool-name="ExampleDS" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
                    <driver>h2</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>sa</user-name>
                        <password>sa</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/EvelingDs" pool-name="EvelingDs" enabled="true" use-java-context="true">
                    <connection-url>jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/proyectoEveling</connection-url>
                    <driver>mysql</driver>
                    <security>
                        <user-name>infra</user-name>
                        <password>infra_pass</password>
                    </security>
                </datasource>
                <drivers>
                    <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
                        <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
                    </driver>
                      <driver name="mysql" module="com.mysql"/>
                </drivers>
            </datasources>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:deployment-scanner:1.1">
            <deployment-scanner path="deployments" relative-to="jboss.server.base.dir" scan-interval="5000"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ee:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:ejb3:1.2">
            <session-bean>
                <stateless>
                    <bean-instance-pool-ref pool-name="slsb-strict-max-pool"/>
                </stateless>
                <stateful default-access-timeout="5000" cache-ref="simple"/>
                <singleton default-access-timeout="5000"/>
            </session-bean>
            <pools>
                <bean-instance-pools>
                    <strict-max-pool name="slsb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                    <strict-max-pool name="mdb-strict-max-pool" max-pool-size="20" instance-acquisition-timeout="5" instance-acquisition-timeout-unit="MINUTES"/>
                </bean-instance-pools>
            </pools>
            <caches>
                <cache name="simple" aliases="NoPassivationCache"/>
                <cache name="passivating" passivation-store-ref="file" aliases="SimpleStatefulCache"/>
            </caches>
            <passivation-stores>
                <file-passivation-store name="file"/>
            </passivation-stores>
            <async thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <timer-service thread-pool-name="default">
                <data-store path="timer-service-data" relative-to="jboss.server.data.dir"/>
            </timer-service>
            <remote connector-ref="remoting-connector" thread-pool-name="default"/>
            <thread-pools>
                <thread-pool name="default">
                    <max-threads count="10"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="100" unit="milliseconds"/>
                </thread-pool>
            </thread-pools>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:infinispan:1.2" default-cache-container="hibernate">
            <cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query">
                <local-cache name="entity">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="local-query">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <local-cache name="timestamps">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </local-cache>
            </cache-container>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jaxrs:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jca:1.1">
            <archive-validation enabled="true" fail-on-error="true" fail-on-warn="false"/>
            <bean-validation enabled="true"/>
            <default-workmanager>
                <short-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </short-running-threads>
                <long-running-threads>
                    <core-threads count="50"/>
                    <queue-length count="50"/>
                    <max-threads count="50"/>
                    <keepalive-time time="10" unit="seconds"/>
                </long-running-threads>
            </default-workmanager>
            <cached-connection-manager/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jdr:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.1">
            <show-model value="true"/>
            <remoting-connector/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jpa:1.0">
            <jpa default-datasource=""/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:mail:1.0">
            <mail-session jndi-name="java:jboss/mail/Default">
                <smtp-server outbound-socket-binding-ref="mail-smtp"/>
            </mail-session>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:osgi:1.2" activation="lazy">
            <properties>
                <!-- Specifies the beginning start level of the framework -->
                <property name="org.osgi.framework.startlevel.beginning">1</property>
            </properties>
            <capabilities>
                <!-- modules registered with the OSGi layer on startup -->
                <capability name="javax.servlet.api:v25"/>
                <capability name="javax.transaction.api"/>
                <!-- bundles started in startlevel 1 -->
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.log" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.osgi.logging" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.apache.felix.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
                <capability name="org.jboss.as.osgi.configadmin" startlevel="1"/>
            </capabilities>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:pojo:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:remoting:1.1">
            <connector name="remoting-connector" socket-binding="remoting" security-realm="ApplicationRealm"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:resource-adapters:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:sar:1.0"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:security:1.1">
            <security-domains>
                <security-domain name="other" cache-type="default">
                    <authentication>
                        <login-module code="Remoting" flag="optional">
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                        <login-module code="RealmUsersRoles" flag="required">
                            <module-option name="usersProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-users.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="rolesProperties" value="${jboss.server.config.dir}/application-roles.properties"/>
                            <module-option name="realm" value="ApplicationRealm"/>
                            <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass"/>
                        </login-module>
                    </authentication>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-web-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
                <security-domain name="jboss-ejb-policy" cache-type="default">
                    <authorization>
                        <policy-module code="Delegating" flag="required"/>
                    </authorization>
                </security-domain>
            </security-domains>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:threads:1.1"/>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:transactions:1.1">
            <core-environment>
                <process-id>
                    <uuid/>
                </process-id>
            </core-environment>
            <recovery-environment socket-binding="txn-recovery-environment" status-socket-binding="txn-status-manager"/>
            <coordinator-environment default-timeout="300"/>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:web:1.1" default-virtual-server="default-host" native="false">
            <connector name="http" protocol="HTTP/1.1" scheme="http" socket-binding="http"/>
            <virtual-server name="default-host" enable-welcome-root="true">
                <alias name="localhost"/>
                <alias name="example.com"/>
            </virtual-server>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:webservices:1.1">
            <modify-wsdl-address>true</modify-wsdl-address>
            <wsdl-host>${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}</wsdl-host>
            <endpoint-config name="Standard-Endpoint-Config"/>
            <endpoint-config name="Recording-Endpoint-Config">
                <pre-handler-chain name="recording-handlers" protocol-bindings="##SOAP11_HTTP ##SOAP11_HTTP_MTOM ##SOAP12_HTTP ##SOAP12_HTTP_MTOM">
                    <handler name="RecordingHandler" class="org.jboss.ws.common.invocation.RecordingServerHandler"/>
                </pre-handler-chain>
            </endpoint-config>
        </subsystem>
        <subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:weld:1.0"/>
    </profile>
    <interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
        <!-- TODO - only show this if the jacorb subsystem is added  -->
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <!--
              ~  Used for IIOP sockets in the standard configuration.
              ~                  To secure JacORB you need to setup SSL 
              -->
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:127.0.0.1}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>
    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="osgi-http" interface="management" port="8090"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>
</server>
```

---

jboss-as-7.1.1.Final\modules\com\mysql\module.xml

```
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.1" name="com.mysql">

    <resources>
        <resource-root path="mysql-connector-java-5.1.34-bin.jar"/>
        <!-- Insert resources here -->
    </resources>
    <dependencies>
        <module name="javax.api"/>
        <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
        <module name="javax.servlet.api" optional="true"/>
    </dependencies>
</module>
```

Thank you for the help you can...

Answer (score 3):

Although this one looks old for the benefit of others who happen to stumble upon the same one

please add

```html
<driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>  to your driver definition in standalone.xml

  complete entry  

<drivers>
 <driver name="com.mysql" module="com.mysql">
 <driver-class>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</driver-class>
 <xa-datasource-class>com.mysql.jdbc.jdbc2.optional.MysqlXADataSource</xa-datasource-class>
 </driver>                 
</drivers>
```